# How to connect telegram bot to vps (windows server)?

Tags: php, vps, php-telegram-bot

i have a Virtual Server (vps) and i have a Telegram bot with php language.
my vps is multi user (3 user are using server and i am admin)

now i wants connect bot to server , and bot notice me that how login to server.
For exapmle : when user 1 login to server , the bot send me a message "User 1 login to server".

it is possible? if answer is yes , how?

thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this solution to run a script when a user log in https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows

and the script would send a message with telegram bot.
the easy way would be a python script